# font forge remove glyphs

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I'm trying to remove specific ligature characters using FontForge because there are too many substitution tables which are not really annotated well.
So I tried pressing "remove and detach glyph" for one of the ligature glyphs, which makes the glyph disappear in the table.

However, in the metric window (and upon reinstalling the font), the ligature is still there.

How do I remove ligature characters directly in the glyph table?